# Customized creation of dictionary with different sizes of key and values

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
k = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
v = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

I would like to make a dictionary that has this form:

```
d = {0:'1', 1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'2', 4:'3', 5:'3', ...}
```

That is every two elements from k will be mapped to the same element from v sequentially.
I would be grateful If someone can guide me through how can I achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with your initial data:

```
k = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
v = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

And then we convert `k` into a list of 2-tuples:

```
kiter = iter(k)
kpairs = zip(kiter, kiter)
```

You could also write the above as...

```
kpairs = zip(*[iter(k)]*2)
```

...see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks) for more discussion about splitting an iterable into chunks.

This gets us an iterator that returns:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), ...]
```

We can `zip` that with `v`, which gets us:

```
[((0, 1), '1'), ((2, 3), '2'), ((4, 5), '3'), ...]
```

Which we can use in a [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) to get the desired final value:

```
final ={y: x[1] for x in (zip(kpairs,v)) for y in x[0]}
```

After running the above code, `final` contains:

```
{0: '1',
 1: '1',
 2: '2',
 3: '2',
 4: '3',
 5: '3',
 6: '4',
 7: '4',
 8: '5',
 9: '5',
 10: '6',
 11: '6',
 12: '7',
 13: '7',
 14: '8',
 15: '8',
 16: '9',
 17: '9',
 18: '10',
 19: '10'}
```

---

The above dictionary comprehension could be unrolled into a pair of `for` loops like this:

```
for x in zip(kpairs,v):
    for y in x[0]:
        final[y] = x[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and well elaborated answer